# What is the correct syntax for returning IQueryable to a data-bound control

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm doing some refactoring to eliminate SqlDataSource controls. Below is code from my business logic class that is intended to return a list of images for a given ID.

```
public class BusinessLogic
{        
    public IQueryable<SBMData2.File> GetPackageImages(int id)
    {
        SBMData2.SBMDataContext db = new SBMData2.SBMDataContext();

        IQueryable<SBMData2.File> PackageImages = from f in db.Files
                                                  where f.PackageID == id
                                                  select f;
        return PackageImages;

    }
}
```

In my code behind I'm trying to bind the IQueryable object to an asp repeater by doing something like the following.

```
int id = RadGrid1.SelectedValues["id"].ToString();
Repeater1.DataSource = BusinessLogic.GetPackageImages(id);
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

My item template contains a simple image tag that binds FileName from the bound IQueryable object.  For example:

```
<img src="PackageFile.ashx?Thumb=true&Id=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName").ToString() %>" alt="loading image ..."/>
```

My question has two parts.  First, is my syntax correct inside of the BusinessLogic class? I suspect it is not because I cannot access GetPackageImages from my code behind.  Second, I am almost certain that I did not specify my datasource correctly.  How can I correct that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared it as an *instance* method, but you're trying to get at it as a *static* method, unless you've got a property called `BusinessLogic` of type `BusinessLogic`... Try just making it static:

```
public static IQueryable<SBMData2.File> GetPackageImages(int id)
```

I don't know much about data binding, but it looks like it *could* be okay.

Personally I wouldn't use a query expression in `GetPackageImages`, and I also wouldn't name local variables with PascalCase, mind you. I'd just use:

```
SBMData2.SBMDataContext db = new SBMData2.SBMDataContext();
return db.Files.Where(f => f.PackageID == id);
```

Comment: Thank you Jon.  This was a very helpful and clear.  I'm still trying to figure out the correct way to data bind this query.

Comment: It turns out the data binding works exactly as shown in the question.